# Howto dump xml data with xmerl_scan even if syntax error

Tags: xml, erlang

When using a xml file with syntax error with xmerl_scan:file the output indicate the line and column number as :

```
1> xmerl_scan:file('failed.xml').
2542- fatal: {endtag_does_not_match,{was,request,should_have_been,http}}
** exception exit: {fatal,{{endtag_does_not_match,{was,request,
                                                   should_have_been,http}},
                           {file,'failed.xml'},
                           {line,77},
                           {col,8}}}
```

The problem is the file failed.xml is composed with a lot of ENTITY so the original file doesn't contains 77 lines, the debug is not easy is this case. Howto dump the final xml really analyzed by xmerl_sacn to debug the xml ? Is the any options to pass to xmerl_scan ? I read the doc but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use xmerl_sax_parser:file/2 as proppose by Lars Thorsen in erlang-questions list
http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-October/075682.html